# What does &= mean?

Tags: c, termcap

I'm using termcaps and I don't understand what `&=` means in this example:

```
term.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON);
```

Could anyone explain to me how this works?

Comment: `term.c_lflag = (term.c_lflag) & (~(ICANON))`

Comment: The semantic meaning is to turn off the `ICANON` flag, leaving canonical input mode. (Once the new `c_lflag` value is set.)

Comment: A bit of an old question, but for people arriving from google: `a &= b` is the same as `a = a & b`.

Answer (score 10):

That's a common way to set a specific bit to 0 in an integer that represents a bitfield.

```
unsigned a = ...;
// ...
unsigned int mask = 1 << 11;  // mask for 12th bit
a |=  mask;  // set 12th bit to 1
a &= ~mask;  // set 12th bit to 0
```

Enabling a bit works by bitwise-`or`ing a number with a mask that looks like `000010000`.
Disabling a bit works by bitwise-`and`ing a number with a mask like `111101111` (hence the need for `~`, which stands for bitwise negation).

Note that there are also other options for managing bitfields:

- in C++, using `std::bitset` or even `std::vector<bool>`
- in C or C++, using a bitfield struct like

  ```
  struct Foo {
     int foo_enabled : 1;
     int bar_enabled : 1;
     // ...
  };
  ```

Answer (score 5):

`&=` means `Bit Wise AND`  and then assign. For example

```
term.c_lflag = (term.c_lflag) & (~(ICANON))
```

First, do t`erm.c_lflag & ~(ICANON)` then assign to `term.c_lflag`

Answer (score 2):

The code turns off the ICANON bit, as Schwartz explain in comment: the ICANON defines a bit through a mask, e.g. `0x8000` (the ICANON bit is the one having value 1), when you apply the bitwise [*not*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#NOT) operator, `~`, all bits are "inverted" and you have (if the values are 16bit wide) `0x7FFF`. If you put in bitwise [*and*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND) (`&`) this value with x, the result is to keep unchanged all bits of x matching a "1" bit in the mask `0x7FFF`, and "turn off" the bits of x matching a "0" bit in the mask, which is exactly the ICANON bit in this specific case.

About `x &= a`, as already explained, it can be considered just syntactic sugar for `x = x & a`.

Answer (score 1):

```
term.c_lflag = (term.c_lflag) & (~ICANON)
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not much different from the operator `+=`. Just like it `term.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON);` should have the effect of `term.c_lflag = term.c_lflag & (~ICANON);` but "in place". You will not create a temporary but instead you will modify `term.c_lflag`. Please note here `&` is the bitwise AND operator.