# Bitwise and doesn't work on unsigned long

Tags: c, bitwise-operators, bitwise-and, bitwise-xor, bitwise-or

I have this code where I use *"bitwise and"* (`&`) to try and change `x`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void){

    unsigned long x = 0;
    printf("x = %lu\n", x);

    x &= 1;
    printf("x = %lu\n", x);

    return 0;

}
```

I compile and execute the code in order to get output:

```
x = 0
x = 0
```

But I expected:

```
x = 0
x = 1
```

Why?

Comment: Mybe you meant `x |= 1;`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does &= mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20948621/what-does-mean)

Comment: Ah sorry! I meant OR! Sorry sorry!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you mean the bitwise inclusive OR operator that can be used to set bits

```
x |= 1;
printf("x = %lu\n", x);
```

Or you could use another bitwise operator: the bitwise exclusive OR operator that can be used to toggle bits

```
x ^= 1;
printf("x = %lu\n", x);
```

Otherwise `0 & 1` will give `0` because initially `x` was initialized by `0`

```
unsigned long x = 0;
```

Here is a demonstration program

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    unsigned long x = 0;
    printf( "x = %lu\n", x );

    x |= 1;
    printf( "x = %lu\n", x );

    x = 0;
    x ^= 1;
    printf( "x = %lu\n", x );
}
```

The program output is

```
x = 0
x = 1
x = 1
```

Comment: This answer seems to imply that `x |= 1` and `x ^= 1` are interchangeable. It would be better to stress that `|=` *sets* a bit, while `^=` *toggles* the bit.